# Is this multitasking related quote correct?

Tags: process, parallel-processing, computer-science, concurrent-processing

> When running on a multicore system, multitasking OSs can truly execute
>   multiple tasks concurrently

I saw this sentence in Nathional Instrument's website and I think "concurrently" should be "parallel". Am I right?

Link: http://www.ni.com/white-paper/6424/en/

Comment: Yes. This is right.

Comment: You mean I'm right? @paul kramme

Comment: Yes. You are right...

Comment: Could you upvote my comments then?

Comment: And by the way... This article is BS. A "multitask os" is simply switching between tasks. And this is so fast that it feels like multitasking, but there is only one task running at any time. The diagrams are right.

Comment: btw, I'm a freshman in stackoverflow. So I need some time to know how to use it. :)

Comment: If you hover over the left side on the comments, youll see a little arrow.